# Get checked checkboxes on form submit and insert values into textarea

Tags: php, javascript

I am having trouble with forms!

The picture below is how i would like to have the interface set up. Basically it consists of a textarea, then a form with 'Submit' buttons, then a drop down box.
The red outlined box is a div whose contents changes depending on the value selected from the dropdown box, whose current value is 'Player'.

I can't seem to get the following behaviour to work: depending on the number of checkboxes clicked, output a phrase in the textarea a certain number of times upon pressing the 'Defend' button.

[image]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: try to play with `onchange` function of the `checkbox`. I cant help much without your initial code

Comment: i would edit with code but i can't seem to figure out a sensible way to indent pages of code. Anyways if you are interested you can view my code here: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?p=1341704#post1341704

Comment: @user2361103 you can use button '{}' on toolbar. Or simply place a code in any way into your question and someone will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what might work (you will need to change it to suit your needs):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function checkboxes()
{
if(document.getElementById('checkbox_1_id').checked&&document.getElementById('checkbox_2_id').checked == false)
{
document.getElementById('textarea_id').value = "First checkbox has been checked";
}
else if(document.getElementById('checkbox_1_id').checked == false&&document.getElementById('checkbox_2_id').checked)
{
document.getElementById('textarea_id').value = "Second checkbox checked";
}
else if(document.getElementById('checkbox_1_id').checked&&document.getElementById('checkbox_2_id').checked)
{
document.getElementById('textarea_id').value = "Both checkboxes checked";
}
}
</script>

<input type = "checkbox" id = "checkbox_1_id" >
<input type = "checkbox" id = "checkbox_2_id" >
<input type = "button" onclick = "checkboxes()" value = "defend">
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. but what i was wanting to achieve was to have the messages display AFTER the user clicks the 'defend'(submit form) button rather than have the messages display as soon as the checkboxes are changed.